# Как поменять родительный падеж в temporals.format(...)?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Использую Thymeleaf и при выводе месяца, он почему-то выводится в родительном падеже, и я никак не могу понять почему.

```html
<input class="date-visible form-control" 
th:case="MONTH" 
th:attr="format='MMMM YYYY'"
th:value="${#temporals.format(date, 'MMMM YYYY')}"/>
```

И вот как выглядит в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть есть какой-то параметр в функции "temporals.format", который отвечает за падеж?

Comment: попробуйте `LLLL` вместо `MMMM`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с [Java 8](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7079560) `'M'` в [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), новом [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) и т.п. выводит имя месяца в зависимости от контекста. Т.е. если в форматной строке есть еще какие-то элементы даты - в родительном падеже.

Для обозначения имени месяца в именительном падеже (stand-alone form) используется символ `'L'`.

```
<input class="date-visible form-control" 
th:case="MONTH" 
th:attr="format='MMMM YYYY'"
th:value="${#temporals.format(date, 'LLLL YYYY')}"/>
```